# How to Parse (not get) an HTTP Request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, eventmachine

I have an integration test which uses eventmachine to receive http requests.  This is my eventmachine handler:

```
class NotificationRecipient < EM::Connection
  def receive_data(data)
    EM.stop
  end
end
```

I need to test various properies of the received request, e.g. I want to extract a json payload from an HTTP POST request string I've received like this.  Is there a nicely packaged way to do it?

Googling finds lots of ways to make a request and parse the response, e.g. rest-client will parse response automatically.  However, since I'm receiving the request, not making it, none of these ways work for me.

Comment: How do you receive the request?

Comment: More information is needed here.  How are you receiving the POST? Rails? Sinatra? Other?  Every framework has its own idiosyncrasies, s we need more information to give you any help.

Comment: I'm using eventmachine, and have updated the question to reflect this.  I'm happy to use functionality built in to eventmachine.  I had assumed that there would be some generic http gem independent of the specific frameworks for sending and receiving.

Comment: Perhaps [httpparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) can serve your needs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would make use of `WEBrick`. [`WEBrick::HTTPRequest`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPRequest.html) has a serviceable parser, and all you need to do is pass an `IO` object to its `parse` method and you have yourself an object you can manipulate.

This example declares a POST request with a JSON body in a string and uses `StringIO` to make it accessible as an `IO` object.

```
require 'webrick'
require 'stringio'

Request = <<-HTTP
POST /url/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my.hostname.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 62

{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 25
}
HTTP

req = WEBrick::HTTPRequest.new(WEBrick::Config::HTTP)
req.parse(StringIO.new(Request))

puts req.path
req.each { |head| puts "#{head}:  #{req[head]}" }
puts req.body
```

**output**

```
/url/path
host:  my.hostname.com
content-type:  application/json
content-length:  62
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 25
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Did the job, and is independent of the web framework.

Comment: @Borodin - how do you send the request?